# What is the spray pattern for the Grease Gun in Call of Duty: World War 2?

Tags: call-of-duty-ww2

What fire pattern will the Grease Gun create when you just hold down fire? What is the spray pattern to control the spray?

Please assume no attachements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what a firing range is for.  Wherever you can edit a class and choose a weapon you get the option to take that weapon to the firing range and test it for whatever you want.

If you're **not aiming down the sight** you will spray just everywhere, even if you're going for 2-3 shot bursts.

- spraying will end up in a circular pattern
- bursting 2-3 shots is pretty much randomly filling the above pattern

**While aiming down the sight** the *spray* pattern is pretty much upwards only slightly going left and right. So you need to aim low, if you're going to spray someone down with that gun.

Controlling the spray can easily be done like with most weapons:

- 1 shot bursts are most accurate (*very* accurate)
- bursts of 2-4 shots are ok (slightly hitting high)
- everything else = spray